# How do I add a CLI argument to find files >, <, or = a given size?

Tags: python, file, arguments, size

I am basically trying to have three arguments for CLI user input:

1. Folder path
2. <, >, or =
3. File size

With these arguments, I want my application to fetch information for all files in the folder path that meet the size arguments. Then I want it to print the file name, size, and date created. Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys, os, time
try:
    folder = sys.argv[1]
    fileSize = int(sys.argv[2])
    
except IndexError:
    print("Input folder path, > < =, and file size in KB's.")
    sys.exit()
except ValueError:
    print("File size in KB's after path.")
    sys.exit()

# Get all files
for (root, dir, files,) in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        size = os.path.getsize(path)/1024
        seconds = os.path.getctime(path)

        if size > fileSize:
            print("Name:", file)
            print("Size: %.2f KB"% size)
            print("Created: ",time.strftime("%d %B %Y",time.localtime(seconds)))
            print()
```

How do I add an argument to allow the user to define what size files the application will fetch by using greater than, less than, or equal to symbols? Currently it is finding files that are greater than. Thank you!

Comment: `size = os.path.getsize(path)/1024` is how many kilobytes the file is, so then in whatever variable you keep the =>< argument, you can check if the variable is =, check for equality, if the variable is less than, check for < etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you mean by "add an argument", or where you want to add it *to*. It's not clear to me what you think `argument` actually means here, actually. Are you talking about the *command line* arguments (`sys.argv`)? In that case - how did you "add" the *existing* arguments? Why not use the same approach again? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Is the question simply about how to *interpret* the symbol `<`, `=` or `>` and *choose what to do* according to which symbol was typed? Well - maybe you can think of some approaches for that already? Like, there's something specific you want to do `if` the symbol is `<`, etc., right? You already know how to write logic like that (since your program already has such logic and is correct), so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @BanjoMan That line converts bytes to kilobytes. I think I understand what you're saying and I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, I was referring to the (sys.argv) as arguments. I added another command line argument like this: (sizeSymbol = sys.argv[2]) and I moved the fileSize argument to argument 3. Now I'm stuck on how the app will handle that sizeSymbol argument.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is there a way I can change the line that has `if size > fileSize:` to something like this `if size sizeSymbol fileSize:` This way the operator that was entered in the command line will go in that if statement?

Comment: I think the problem is `<` and `>` will be interpreted as file redirection commands by the shell, **not** as arguments to be passed to the program being run. You may be able to workaround that by putting them in quotes.

Comment: @martineau it didn't work with the quotes around the symbol but it works if I use words instead of symbols like _**is**, **greater**,_ or _**smaller**._

Comment: In that case you might want to use shorter words, like **eq**, **gt**, and **lt**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are taking arguments only for folder and for fileSize, based on IndexError message I assume you would want to have something like this in args:

> C:\Users\xxx\ > 2

But based on ValueError message you want size second, doesn't matter the order in this case you should also take one more argument that will check whatever sign is in input, it will already be a string and you can do checking on fileSizes depending on that sign later on just check what is the sign

Comment: I now have args like this:
`folder = sys.argv[1]
sizeSymbol = sys.argv[2]
fileSize = int(sys.argv[3])`

Do you know a simple way to adjust the `if` statement to be based off the symbol used in the command line argument?

Comment: Well, simplest way would be just going:
`if sizeSymbol == '=':
    if size = fileSize:...`
etc

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was thinking. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Oreo5 or to make it at least a bit nicer you can move actual size checking to functions and checking input symbol to execute this function

Comment: Unfortunately if I use > in command line it creates a file named by what comes after it. For example: `python filechecker.py "C:\" > 1000` will create a new file in C:\ named 1000. Is there any way around this?

Comment: you might change it for string names like: "greater" "equal" "lower"; use escape sign; or put it in ""